# How do I grant Auth to an Application Pool to a seperate server

Tags: iis, permissions, ssrs

I have a WebServer running IIS, and hosting a number of Webservices.

I have a new requirement to allow a WebService (Currently running as AppPoolIdentity) to connect to SSRS on a seperate server.

Right now, if I log onto the webserver and browse to the other server, I get the standard login page. If I enter my credentials for the second server in there, then I can see the SSRS.

So, how (and where) do I create a user for the Web Service App Pool so it can seamlessly and silently have access to SSRS on the other server.

I have tried using the credentials of an account that is configured on the SSRS server, but as that doesn't exist on the web server, the app pool identity won't take it. Is it simply a case of creating the same account on both servers, and having to manage 2 sets of credentials? (we have no AD in this set up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have two use accounts (one on each server) with the same name and password. Then run your application Pool under that user-account. Give limited permission to the account, to just do what it is suppose to do.

The AppPoolIdentity account has no access to the network or other servers.